# Binding basis using a Flex Layout xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

It is possible, in this case, to replace the `new FlexBasis(0.3f, true)` by a binding ?

```
FlexLayout ftk = new FlexLayout
{
    Direction = FlexDirection.Row
};
FrameMenu customFrameAide = new FrameMenu();
FlexLayout.SetBasis(customFrameAide, new FlexBasis(0.3f, true));
ftk.Children.Add(customFrameAide);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to  replace the new FlexBasis(0.3f, true) by a binding ?

Of course we can . **Basis** is a Bindable Property in **FlexLayout** if we check source code

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BasisProperty;
```

So if you want to set binding in code behind .

Firstly, you need to implement the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** if the **Basis** will change in runtime .

#### in ContentPage (Or ViewModel)

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage,INotifyPropertyChanged
```

```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    


    FlexBasis basis;
    public FlexBasis Basis {

        get {

            return basis;
        
        }

        set
        {
            basis = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Basis");
        }
    
    }
```

And set binding like following (it seems that customFrameAide is a subclass of FlexLayout,right?)

```
 customFrameAide.SetBinding(FlexLayout.BasisProperty, "Basis");
```